# Enlightenment (E16) not recognizing images in ~/.enlightenment/backgrounds

Tags: ubuntu, enlightenment

I've got Enlightenment (E16) installed on Ubuntu 9.10, and i'm starting it using the session manager (I elect E16 from the drop down list).   However e not recognizing images in ~/.enlightenment/backgrounds

How can i get it to scan this directory, right now I have 4 jpgs in there.

Thanks,
Roy

Update: going for the tumbleweed badge on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e16 *should* use the default directory of ~/.e16. Why it doesn't, I don't know. However, you may be interested in trying:

`ln -s .enlightenment .e16`

to see if that works.

---

Sorry about killing the badge, if you haven't gotten it already, but I just had this **sick, disgusting** urge to answer your question :-)

Comment: technically, I just renamed my .enlightenment folder to .e16